# CSS overlapping border of parent element, negative margin

Tags: html, css, border

I have nested elements, the container has a border style of one sort and I want some of the elements inside it to have their own border overlapping the container's border. I tried using negative margin, but the border of the child is hidden underneath the parent's (seems to be overflow issue).

HTML:

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="itemlist">
        <ol>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li class="special">Abc</li>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li class="special">Abc</li>
            <li>Abc</li>
            <li>Abc</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-left: 3px solid #76ff03;
}

.right .itemlist {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.itemlist > ol > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #76ff03;
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.itemlist > ol > li:hover, .itemlist > ol > li.special {
    border-left: 10px solid #2196f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2196f3;
    margin-left: -3px;

}
```

I've seen some examples of this done and can make it work in some cases, but not consistently. I have an example JSFiddle with some layout, below is a picture of whet two of the list elements look like and what I want them to look like.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkondratowicz/e6uunLa4/1/

[image: Current and desired styling]

Comment: Probably not using borders...perhaps a box-shadow or pseudo-element.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried using a `:before` pseudo-element positioned to the left, but it hides "under" the parent's border too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it removing the margin on it's parent container and adding it to each row individually

```
.right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #78909c;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.itemlist > ol > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #76ff03;

    border-left: 3px solid #76ff03;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Here are the styles you need using box-shadow

```
.itemlist > ol > li {
    box-shadow: inset 3px -1px 0px 0px #76ff03;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.right .itemlist {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 0px 0px 0px #76ff03;
}


.itemlist > ol > li:hover, .itemlist > ol > li.special {
    box-shadow: inset 10px -1px 0px 0px #2196f3;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #78909c;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnjn17uL/2/